# Can a Control from an Access Userform be used in a Query Field?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, userform

I currently have a Microsoft Access 2010 database for a whole bunch of medical providers. Each provider record has almost 200 specialties that can either have "Yes", "P/C" or "No" as entries.

I am trying to make a search form that would allow the user to select a specialty from a combobox and have a query search the database for every provider whom has that field name at either a "Yes" or a "P/C"

My issue is I do not know quite how to take a user input from a form and use that value to search by a field.

The following only gives me syntax errors.

```
"'" & Forms!fProviderSearch!cmbbxSearchProviderSpecialty & "'"

Expr 1: Forms!fProviderSearch!cmbbxSearchProviderSpecialty
```

My question is then is this even possible? Can a Userform's control value be placed into the query field to search?

I have tried to solve this using VBA and that was just a big unsuccessful mess.

Comment: Seems you misunderstand the purpose of a form. What's the query supposed to do if the form isn't loaded? Queries don't care about forms, but they can take parameters. Look into parameterizing your queries, not for ways to hack up a coupling between a query and some form. The parameter value can come from a form, but the query should be fundamentally and blissfully unaware of where the parameter value came from.

Comment: Your second format should work just fine. You  can type in the forms! expression as you have into the query builder (in the criteria part of the query grid). You don't need quotes or to concatenate when you do this.

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick responses. The query as it stands will pull the providers first name, last name and initials if there is no population on the form. 

Albert - I understand that I can use that method for the criteria. What I am trying to do is to take the users entry and place it in the field section on the query grid, not the criteria. My only option might be to create over 200 queries for each specific specialty.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there is no way to take a users input and place it into the field section of the query grid. Access' database format does not allow for this.